# C++ What's the usage difference between get and typecasting? Which one should I use?

Tags: c++, casting

```
#include <iosteam>
using namespace std;

Class A
{
  int k;

public:

  int getK() { return k; }

  operator int() { return k; }

};

int main()
{
  A a;
  cout << a.getK() << " " << int(a) << endl;
}
```

What's the difference, and which one should I use? I'm wondering if typecasting returns a reference and getK returns a copy.

Comment: Typecasting is more appropriate for things like a `BigInteger` class to convert to an int.

Comment: @James `int` is immutable? What do you mean by that? Surely you can change the value of an int...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is that typecasting can be implicit.

```
int i = a;
```

Note that c++11 allow you to force cast operator to be explicitly called.

```
explicit operator int() { return k; }
```

Comment: Except for when it isn't. Don't you love C++?

Answer (score 1):

They are both returning copies. Providing a cast operator usually is for when casting is necessary. For example you might do something like this maybe:

```
#include <iosteam>
using namespace std;

Class A
{
  double k;

public:
  A(double v) : k(v) {}
  double getK() { return k; }
  operator int() { return static_cast<int>(k); }
};

int main()
{
  A a(3.14);
  cout << a.getK() << " " << int(a) << endl; // 3.14 3
}
```

In general I avoid cast operators entirely because I prefer explicit casting.

Comment: That's easily solved in C++11: `explicit operator int() {...}`

Comment: You are correct sir, typecast operators are still more appropriate for user defined objects being used as system defined objects. In the OP's case the accessor method makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

It returns what the return type is.  If you cast to a reference, then that's what you get back.  What you're doing both times is making a copy.

The "difference" is what your method does.  Your "cast" could add 5 to it and then return it.  Or anything you want.

As for appropriateness, as chris said in the first comment, it's usually a "is your class a  or not?" type question.  Operators should be done for common conversions because your class operates as something, not merely to extract something from it.  That's why it's a separate function to convert strings to integers, rather than being merely a cast on the string class.  Whereas a complex number type can often be cast directly to a double or int, though that strips information from it.  That the conversions can be "abused" is actually why some modern languages don't allow operator overloading.  Others take the approach of while it can be abused, it can also be awesome.  That's the C++ philosophy on most things: give all the tools, let the user do good or bad with them.

I hope that made sense.